# How to add files to specified folder in archive with 7zip command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, archiving, 7-zip

I have folders and files on my disk

```
C:\builds\main.exe
D:\components\a\testa.exe
D:\components\b\testb.exe
D:\components\c\testc.exe
D:\dependencies\abc.dll
```

**Can I create an archive with 7z command line version with folder structure similar to this?**

```
MyArchive.7z
 |- main.exe
 |- abc.dll
 |- components\testa.exe
 |- components\testb.exe
 |- components\testc.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

[Reading this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

You would need to create a batch/script file containing something like this:

```
7z a: -r -t7z MyArchive.7z C:\builds\main.exe D:\components\a\testa.exe D:\components\b\testb.exe D:\components\c\testc.exe D:\dependencies\abc.dll
```

Commands are as follows - **a:** to add to archive, **-r** to make recursive, **-t7z** .7z archive file type.

Note: this is untested.

Comment: I got **compnents\a\testa.exe** instead of **components\testa.exe**, guy

Comment: Then ammend it to suit, does it work? If you can't figure out how to do that yourself then you're on the wrong website. Suggest reading the software [FAQ](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html) and help files.

Comment: Any update on this Peter PAD? Fixed? Tested?